# Handling Nullable references when constructing LambdaExpression dynamically

Tags: c#, lambda, asp.net-3.5, expression-trees, nullable

I have a class represent a generic filter object

```
public class Filter
{
    public string column { get; set; }
    public string operator { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

that I am able to transform in a `LambdaExpression` thanks to code like this

```
public LambdaExpression ToExpression( IQueryable query ) {
    LambdaExpression toReturn = null;
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter( query.ElementType, "p" );
    MemberExpression memberAccess = GetMemberExpression( column, parameter );
    ConstantExpression filter = Expression.Constant( Convert.ChangeType( data, memberAccess.Type ) );
    WhereOperation condition = (WhereOperation)StringEnum.Parse( typeof( WhereOperation ), operator );
    LambdaExpression lambda = BuildLambdaExpression( memberAccess, filter, parameter, condition, data );
    if ( toReturn == null ) {
        toReturn = lambda;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

As per the requirement the `Filter` member `column` can contains a sort of navigation sintax for querying fields that is expressed like `FieldA.FieldB.Description` that translates to:

- Get the value of type T returned from the FieldA property
- Get the value of type T1 returned from the FieldB of T
- Get the value of type T2 returned from the Description of T2

The result is a lambda like this one: `p.FieldA.FieldB.Description == "data"`
and I can use this result as a parameter of the `Where` extension method of any `IQueryable`

The problem comes out when one of the members of the navigation query is a `Nullable` type. In that case, supposing FieldA is nullable, the correct lambda should be

`p.FieldA != null && p.FieldA.FieldB.Description == "data"`

I have tried to implement this check while constructing the `MemberExpression` object using code like this one

```
MemberExpression memberAccess = null;
foreach ( var property in column.Split( '.' ) ) {
    memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property( memberAccess ?? ( p as Expression ), property );
    Type memberType = memberAccess.Type;
    if ( memberType.IsGenericType && 
         memberType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( Nullable<> ) ) {

        //Create here an expression of type : memberAccess != null
    }
}
```

that is good for primitive types but does not work, for example, with other object references, like EF `EntityReference` object instances.
I know I could simply add another condition to the previous `if` like

```
if ( ( memberType.IsGenericType && 
       memberType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( Nullable<> ) ) ||
       memberType.IsClass ) {
}
```

but that seems to me too much generic producing a lambda with too many condition and most of them maybe unuseful.

Is there any way to better individuate nullable references?

Comment: If the expression is destined to Entity Framework, I wouldn't bother. `p.FieldA.FieldB.Description == "data"` simply will be false without any exception if `FieldA` or `FieldB` is null. If it's meant to be compiled and run in memory, it's another story.

Comment: I am using EF first release, the one that works with .NET 3.5. If I do a query like in the sample the query simply does not apply and the result is like I would'nt have specified any filter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the null check unconditional. Checking a value type for null is not illegal.

Comment: My Filter class is already used in a bigger context with groups and other list of rules. If I make the check unconditional the number of expressions in some cases can quickly increase even if they are not strictly needed. Does this would affect performances?

Comment: @Lorenzo Checking for null is no more or less work than checking if a value is nullable, so the check to see if you need to do a null check is the same work in the case of a non-nullable object, and *more* work in the case of a nullable object.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Well, each additional operation adds a little bit to the overhead, sure. But on the other hand, the vast majority of the types used in your scenario will be reference types and needs the null check anyway.